# Using the Master Theorem to solve a recurrence

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have the following recurrence relation, which I am trying to solve using the Master Theorem:
$$
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^{\frac 12} + \log n
$$
Comparing the above recurrence to the recurrence of the form:

$$
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)
$$

We have:

$$
a = 2, b = 2, f(n) = n^{\frac 12} + \log n
$$

$$
n^{\log_ba} = n^{\log_2 2} = n
$$

Comparing $f(n)$ and $n^{\log_b a}$ asymptotically:

$$
f(n) = n^{\frac 12} + \log n
$$

$n^{\log_b a} = n$

Since $n^{\frac 12}$ dominates $\log n$ in $f(n)$, does this mean that the recurrence relation satisfies the first case of the Master Theorem? The first case of the Master Theorem states:

If $f(n) = O(n^{\log_b a -e})$, then $T(n) = Θ(n^{\log_b a})$ for an $e > 0$.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the question right? In your first equation there is no $a$ term. So $\log_2 1= 0$.

Comment: Sorry, the recurrence relation should be 2T(n/2) + n^(1/2) + logn instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you have is correct: $\sqrt n + \log(n) \in O(\sqrt n) = O(n^{\log_2 2 - \frac 12})$ so we are in the first case of the Master theorem.